# c# - Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' Exception from HRESULT : 0x8001010D

Tags: c#, exception

I have a problem my function does not want to run outside of debug mode. It only gets the path I need when the Debugger is on, when I turn it off I get an Exception from HRESULT : 0x8001010D error.

Full error messange:
Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' : 'Transition into COM context 0xad4f80 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)). This is typically because the COM context 0xad4f80 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else and cannot process the context transition. No proxy will be used to service the request on the COM component and calls will be made to the COM component directly. This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for context transition, until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live inside them.'

Here is the function call:

```
                 var proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
                 var title = proc.MainWindowTitle;
                 var procExe = ProcessExecutablePath(proc);
```

And here is the main function:

```
public static string ProcessExecutablePath(Process process)
         {
             try
             {
                 if (process.MainModule != null)
                 {
                     return process.MainModule.FileName;
                 }
             }
             catch
             {
                 var query = $"SELECT ExecutablePath, ProcessID FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = {process.Id}";
                 var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

                 foreach (var o in searcher.Get())
                 {
                     var item = (ManagementObject)o;
                     var id = item["ProcessID"];
                     var path = item["ExecutablePath"];

                     if (path != null && id.ToString() == process.Id.ToString())
                     {
                         return path.ToString();
                     }
                 }
             }

             return "Unknown";
         }
```

[Exception from visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ierxk.png)

if there is a possibility to remove the foreach loop, that would be nice, because i need to extract the ExecutablePath string only (it is taken from Win32_Process Class)

Example result when work in Debug Mode:
ProcID - 3692 ### Exe - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe

I have no idea to solve my issue.

Comment: There is no reason same source code would not work in both debug and release mode.  I would check the timestamp of the executables in both debug and release folder to see if both have same timestamp.  You may be compiling only the debug and not the release.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73775278/21918923
Probably it could help you.
It helped me with the similar exception. I catched it while

> searcher.Get()

method execution. I suppose it is your case too.

The main idea is to run this block in the parallel thread. I use semaphore for the syncronisation of getting result.

My working sample:

```
//starting from your 
//catch {
     Semaphore sm = new Semaphore(1, 2);
     sm.WaitOne();



   string resultString = string.Empty;
    
     Task.Run(() =>
     {           
         //Place your code starting from query here instead of mine --> 
         string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard";
         ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
             new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
         foreach (ManagementObject info in searcher.Get())
         {
              var pr =
                   info.GetPropertyValue("Product").ToString();

               if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pr))
                   continue;
               resultString += pr;
         }
     
         // up to here <---
    
         if (sm != null)
                 sm.Release();
    
     });
    
     sm.WaitOne();
     sm.Release();
     sm.Dispose();
     sm = null;
    
     return resultString;

// } your catch block ends
```